# data preparation for random forest and predictive modeling

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I am working on a predictive modeling exercise using a categorical output (pass/fail: binary 1 or 0) and about 200 features. I have about 350K training examples for this, but I can increase the size of my dataset if needed. Here are a few issues that I running into:

1-  I am dealing with **severely imbalanced classes**. Out of those 350K examples, only 2K are labelled as “fail” (i.e. categorical output = 1). How do I account for this? I know there are several techniques, such as up-sampling with bootstrap;

2- **Most of my features (~ 95%) are categorical** (e.g. city, language, etc.) with less than 5-6 levels each. Do I need to transform them into binary data for each level of a feature? For instance if the feature “city” has 3 levels with New York, Paris, and Barcelona, then I can transform it into 3 binary features: city_New_york, city_Paris, and city_Barcelona;

3 - **Picking the model** itself: I am thinking about a few such as SVM, K-neighbors, Decision tree, Random Forest, Logistic Regression, but my guess is that Random Forest will be appropriate for this because of the large number of categorical features. Any suggestions there?

4 - **If I use Random Forest**, do I need to (a) do feature scaling for the continuous variables (I am guessing not), (b) change my continuous variables to binary, as explained in question 2 above (I am guessing not), (c) account for my severe imbalanced classes, (d) remove missing values.

Answer (score 3):

1. It helps to train with balanced classes (but don't cross validate with them) RF is surprisingly efficient with data, so you won't need all 350k negative samples to train, likely. Choose an equal number of positive examples by sampling with replacement from that pool. Don't forget to leave some positive examples out for validation though.
2. If you are in scikit-learn, use pandas' df.get_dummies() to generate the binary encoding. R does the binary encoding for you for variables that are factors. Behind the scenes it makes a bit vector.
3. I always start with RF because there are so few knobs, it's a good benchmark. After I've straightened out my feature transforms and gotten AUC up, I try the other methods.
4. a) no b) no c) yes d) Yes it needs to be fixed somehow. If you can get away with removing data where any predictor has missing values, great. However if that's not possible, median is a common choice. Let's say a tree is being built, and variable X4 is chosen to split on. RF needs to choose a point on a line and send all the data to either the left or right. What should it do for data where X4 has no value ?  Here is the strategy the ['randomForest' package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForest/randomForest.pdf) takes in R:

> For numeric variables, NAs are replaced with column medians. For factor variables, NAs are replaced with the most frequent levels (breaking ties at random). If object contains no NAs, it is returned unaltered.